# Technical Inequality needed to establish smooth but nowhere analytic function

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

In [this Wikipedia article on a Non-analytic smooth function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function) an estimate is given which is crucial to the argument that the Taylor series only represents the smooth function at the center.

The estimate which currently vexes me is:
$$ \sum_{k \in A, k >q } e^{-\sqrt{k}}k^n \geq e^{-\sqrt{n}}n^n $$
as $n \rightarrow \infty$. In the above $q = 2^m$ for some fixed positive integer $m$ and $A = \{ 2^k \ | \ k \in \mathbb N \}$. My question is simply:

> How can we justify the inequality above ?

I will award a 100pt bounty to whoever helps best as soon as it is allowed by the software of the site. Thanks in advance for your insight on this pesky inequality.

Comment: Note that what you wrote is not what the cited inequality says. You are assuming that the two pieces of the inequality both satisfy a similar inequality. Are you sure that's true? I don't know.

Comment: @MPW I think I see a reason for the other term to have over order $O(q^n)$ as is written, so I conjecture those two parts can be independently established. If Chapper's is correct, this is actually pretty simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article gives that $n \in A$, $n>q$ in the conditions used in deriving that inequality. But this just reduces the problem to a sum of positive terms being larger than one of the terms (i.e. if $a_k \geq 0$ for every $k \in K$, $\sum_{k \in K} a_k \geq a_n$ for any $n \in K$).

Comment: I want to believe, but I think $n$ has a fixed meaning outside the sum over $k$ in this discussion. I will ponder this, I hope you're right.

Comment: Ok, since $f(x)=e^{-\sqrt{x}}x^n$ is increasing, if we consider $k>n$ then $f(k)>f(n)$ which gives $e^{-\sqrt{k}}k^n > e^{-\sqrt{n}}n^n$ and $e^{-\sqrt{k}}k^n$ is a particular term in the sum.. thanks!